# Node: API authentication of 3rd party apps

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, hmac

I am building an API for a mobile APP. However, I want to also be able to allow other apps to use the API. If someone wants access to my API, they would request an clientKey and clientSecret that would be associated to that company (the one who is using the api). If someone makes a request to my API, given the clientKey I'd know which company is making the request and with the secret I could use HMAC signing to check authenticity. If a request is valid, then I will know which company is making the request and therefore can check if the request is valid for that company (a company would only be able to manage its own resources for example).

I am using node + mongoose + passport (for regular app users login).

Questions:

1) Does this seem like a good approach?
2) Are there any security flaws in this scheme?
3) Does anyone know a good stable node module that does this?
4) Any other thoughts are welcome

Long days and pleasant nights

Comment: It seems like a good approach to me but once you clearly define the algorithm you may want to proceed over to Information Security and ask them about it.  Before you do that though, you may want to do a bit more research before reinventing the wheel.  Depending on how much security you need, you may want use a standard protocol rather than your own home-rolled solution. Your api consumers may expect this as well (they may already have an OAuth client layer ready to use, for example)..

Comment: @AlexMA, thanks for the feedback. I posted this question in my college group and a friend told me about Hawk algorithm. Seems to mee a good approach and there is a [module](https://github.com/hueniverse/hawk) for node that implements it. Probably using it.